# Need to get android supported biometric types

Tags: android, android-studio, android-biometric-prompt, android-biometric

I wants to get supported Biometric type user can authenticate.

```
    val biometricManager = BiometricManager.from(this)
when (biometricManager.canAuthenticate()) {
    BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_SUCCESS -> {
        //In here I needs to get the Biometric Type 
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "supported Biometric type"?

Comment: @CommonsWare fingerprint or face recognition or irirs

Comment: @ImeshMadushanka so the answer can be long or short.
Short one: Current Biometric API do not have relevant methods for this.
Long one:
You can use 3rd-party solutions, for example AdvancedBiometricCompat:

 
```if(BiometricPromptCompat.getAvailableAuthRequests()[0].type == BiometricType.BIOMETRIC_FACE) //do something with face```

The types list is here https://github.com/sergeykomlach/AdvancedBiometricPromptCompat/tree/main#supported-types-of-biometric-authentication